# Rapidminer Numerical to Binominal - RAM Issue

Tags: out-of-memory, rapidminer, market-basket-analysis

In realtion to Rapidminer, I Have a dataset with 3 columns (Transaction ID, Product Description, Value) and approx 1 million rows.

I am trying to apply FP-Growth and Create Association but this keeps failing due to memory at the "Numerical to Binomial" stage of my process . I have allocated 56GB of RAM.

"This process would need more than the maximum amount of available memory. You can either leave......"
[attached example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqSiN.png)

Am I doing something wrong here? I would have thought 56GB of RAM would be more than enough to cope with this.

Any help will be much appreciated

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds that you are using an older version of RapidMiner. With version 6.5 the license model of RapidMiner changed and it no longer has any memory constraints. The process below runs on my machine with 10gb RAM allocated in under 3 seconds:

```
<process version="7.0.001">
  <context>
    <input/>
    <output/>
    <macros/>
  </context>
  <operator activated="true" class="process" compatibility="7.0.001"     expanded="true" name="Process">
    <process expanded="true">
      <operator activated="true" class="generate_data"     compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="68" name="Generate Data" width="90" x="112" y="34">
        <parameter key="number_examples" value="1000000"/>
        <parameter key="number_of_attributes" value="2"/>
      </operator>
      <operator activated="true" class="numerical_to_binominal" compatibility="7.0.001" expanded="true" height="82" name="Numerical to Binominal" width="90" x="313" y="34">
        <parameter key="min" value="-10.0"/>
      </operator>
      <connect from_op="Generate Data" from_port="output" to_op="Numerical to Binominal" to_port="example set input"/>
      <connect from_op="Numerical to Binominal" from_port="example set output" to_port="result 1"/>
      <portSpacing port="source_input 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 1" spacing="0"/>
      <portSpacing port="sink_result 2" spacing="0"/>
    </process>
  </operator>
</process>
```

Comment: I am using: RapidMiner Studio 7.0.001 (rev: 0d4041, platform: WIN64)

Comment: OK, the problem really seems to be the FP-Growth Operator.  This algorithm needs a lot of memory, so with 1 million of examples it is really possible that you ran out of memory. So my best guess is either try it with more memory or reduce your data set.

Comment: Sorry David, what do you mean? Will I need to amend the FP-Growth Operator?